# How to find using dojo whether action class returned Error or Success?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2, dojo

I am using Struts and Jsp and trying to submit a form using dojo Ajax. If the Java action class returns error then I want to show the error by refreshing a particular div on the same page that will fetch the errorMessages from ActionSupport class else if it is success I want to redirect to another page. How can I do this ? I am new to Dojo.

I have handled the success part by defining the page to redirect in xml file. But I am unable to define how to refresh the div on the same when action class returns error.

Comment: By "using Dojo Ajax" you mean what? The deprecated S2 Dojo tags, or a recent, supported version of Dojo itself?

Comment: @DaveNewton, I think it would be a very good thing if the whole integrated Dojo stuff will be removed from the 2.5 milestone version. Are you aware if it's in discussion ? Otherwise, I guess the retro-legacy-abandon-evil-ware-compatibility will win again :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios: [Moves deprecated plugins to struts-archive repo](https://github.com/apache/struts/commit/17d73d21a1203c86aab9c6b887d4e5c01e36a160)

Comment: @AleksandrM 44,969 deletion..... hell, yeah :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :-

```
var xhrArgs = {
  form: dojo.byId("myform"),
  handleAs: "text",
  load: function(data){
    dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Form posted.";
  },
  error: function(error){
    // We'll 404 in the demo, but that's okay.  We don't have a 'postIt' service on the
    // docs server.
    dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Form posted.";
  }
}
// Call the asynchronous xhrPost
var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```